# Really new to java key listener issue

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

quick question, basically can anybody tell me how to make it so that when ever i press a "said" key in java it executes the same task as when i hold it. For example once i click a key he moves a certain amount of distance but the distance he goes is proportional to the time i held the key. What i need is that even if i press it for 0.5 secs or 20 secs it goes the same distance.

Basically this is my Key Events in the main Class (To record the user input).

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        System.out.println("Move up");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        currentSprite = characterDown;
        if (knight.isJumped() == false){
            knight.setDucked(true);
            knight.setSpeedX(0);
        }
        break;



    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        knight.moveRight();
        knight.setMovingRight(true);
        knight.setMOVESPEED(5);
        knight.setMovingRight(false);


        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        knight.jump();
        break;

    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        System.out.println("Stop moving up");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        currentSprite = character;
        knight.setDucked(false);
        break;


    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
       knight.stopRight();
       knight.setMOVESPEED(5);  

       break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        break;

    }

}
```

This is the part where the background scrolls according to the movespeed i have set.

```
//Scrolls Background accordingly.
    if (speedX < 0) {
        centerX += speedX;
    }
    if (speedX == 0 || speedX < 0) {
        bg1.setSpeedX(0);
        bg2.setSpeedX(0);

    }
    if (centerX <= 200 && speedX > 0) {
        centerX += speedX;
    }
    if (speedX > 0 && centerX > 200) {
        bg1.setSpeedX(-getMOVESPEED());
        bg2.setSpeedX(-getMOVESPEED());
    }
```

Hey guys heres the whole character class hope it helps

```
package com.jisc.framework;
```

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Knight {

```
final int JUMPSPEED = -15;
private int MOVESPEED = 5;
final int GROUND = 202;
private int centerX = 350;
private int centerY = GROUND;
private boolean jumped = false;
private boolean movingLeft = false;
private boolean movingRight = false;
private boolean ducked = false;

private static Background bg1 = Main.getBg1();                 
private static Background bg2 = Main.getBg2();

private int speedX = 0;
private int speedY = 0;


public void update() {

    // Moves Character or Scrolls Background accordingly.
    if (speedX < 0) {
        centerX += speedX;
    }
    if (speedX == 0 || speedX < 0) {
        bg1.setSpeedX(0);
        bg2.setSpeedX(0);

    }
    if (centerX <= 200 && speedX > 0) {
        centerX += speedX;
    }
    if (speedX > 0 && centerX > 200) {
        bg1.setSpeedX(-getMOVESPEED());
        bg2.setSpeedX(-getMOVESPEED());
    }

    // Updates Y Position

    if (centerY + speedY >= 202) {
        centerY = 202;
    }else{                        
                    centerY += speedY;
            }

    // Handles Jumping
    if (jumped == true) {
        speedY += 1;

        if (centerY + speedY >= 202) {
            centerY = 202;
            speedY = 0;
            jumped = false;
        }

    }

    // Prevents going beyond X coordinate of 0
    if (centerX + speedX <= 60) {
        centerX = 61;
    }
}

 public void moveRight() {
        if (ducked == false) {

        speedX = MOVESPEED;

   if (MOVESPEED >= 5){
       MOVESPEED ++;

   }

   if (MOVESPEED >= 7 ){
       MOVESPEED = 0;
   }




        }
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        if (ducked == false) {
            speedX = -getMOVESPEED();
        }
    }

    public void stopRight() {
        setMovingRight(false);
        stop();
    }

    public void stopLeft() {
        setMovingLeft(false);
        stop();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (isMovingRight() == false && isMovingLeft() == false) {
            speedX = 0;
        }

        if (isMovingRight() == false && isMovingLeft() == true) {
            moveLeft();
        }

        if (isMovingRight() == true && isMovingLeft() == false) {
            moveRight();
        }

    }

    public void jump() {
        if (jumped == false) {
            speedY = JUMPSPEED;
            jumped = true;
        }

    }

public int getCenterX() {
    return centerX;
}

public int getCenterY() {
    return centerY;
}

public boolean isJumped() {
    return jumped;
}

public int getSpeedX() {
    return speedX;
}

public int getSpeedY() {
    return speedY;
}

public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
    this.centerX = centerX;
}

public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
    this.centerY = centerY;
}

public void setJumped(boolean jumped) {
    this.jumped = jumped;
}

public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
    this.speedX = speedX;
}

public void setSpeedY(int speedY) {
    this.speedY = speedY;
}

public boolean isDucked() {
    return ducked;
}

public void setDucked(boolean ducked) {
    this.ducked = ducked;
}

public boolean isMovingRight() {
    return movingRight;
}

public void setMovingRight(boolean movingRight) {
    this.movingRight = movingRight;
}

public boolean isMovingLeft() {
    return movingLeft;
}

public void setMovingLeft(boolean movingLeft) {
    this.movingLeft = movingLeft;
}

public int getMOVESPEED() {
    return MOVESPEED;
}

public void setMOVESPEED(int mOVESPEED) {
    MOVESPEED = mOVESPEED;
}
```

}

Comment: You gave contradictory requirements.  _"For example once i **click** a key he moves a **certain amount of distance** but the distance he goes is proportional to the **time** i **held** the key."_  Next you say _"What i need is that even if i **press** it for $0.5$ secs or $20$ secs it goes the **same distance**."_  This suggests the distance is _not_ proportional to the time you held the key--instead the distance is a constant value.  You need to say whether the action is the same for a **key press, hold, then release** vs. merely a **key clicked** event and, if different, how?

Comment: Yes i want the distance to not be proportional to they time i held the key i want it to be a constant value. Can you look at my code and tell me waht to chance

Answer (score 2):

Use a boolean flag. This goes in your `keyPressed` method.

```
private boolean canMoveUp = true; // same for up, down, etc.
...
case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
    if (canMoveUp)
    {
        System.out.println("Move up");
        canMoveUp = false;
    }
    break;
```

That alone will only work once. You have to make moving again possible when the key is released. This goes in your `keyReleased` method.

```
case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
    System.out.println("Stop moving up");
    canMoveUp = true;
    break;
```

This will ensure that you only move once when you press a key, and allow you to press that key any number of times.

Comment: Didnt work same problem i think the problem is how i scroll my background or character or something

Comment: @user3695829 You may need to specify a timer to actually notice a difference, based on your update rate and fps.